# views-more.tpl.php does not work

Tags: theming, 6

I followed the Drupal documentation (https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme%21views-more.tpl.php/6) and saved my views-more.tpl.php inside my theme folder. However, it does not work and seems like my website does not take my views-more.tpl.php. I cleared cache under /settings/performance and wonder what else I should do?

Comment: Did you tried cleaning theme registry cache? This can be done via using [admin_menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_menu) or Go to some view > Theme: information (under Basic settings). You can also use [Devel Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) to see which template is loading.

Comment: i did cleared cache following the instruction here (which is same as going to admin/settings/performance :( :  
https://www.drupal.org/node/337176

Comment: Sometimes for me cleaning cache from performance dosen't work so I prefer to do it from admin_menu or Drush.

Comment: Hello again, I have tested this in my dev website and view-more.tpl.php is working for me. I just added this file under mytheme/templates/view.more.tpl.php and cleared cache. Which parent theme are you using? and views version?

Comment: **[On February 24th 2016, Drupal 6 will reach end of life and no longer be supported.](https://www.drupal.org/drupal-6-eol)**

Comment: I just moved it to templates folder, but still not working
btw, is there sth has to do with theme_more_link function? I am doing this for my company, so I tried not to touch the theme.inc file.

Comment: I don't think there will be something to do with theme_more_link function. If you want to update view more link button then view-more.tpl.php is the correct file. Tell me which steps you are performing to achieve this and little bit more info of your theme structure?

Comment: the views-more was saved under themes/mytheme/views-more.tpl.php (mytheme.info, page.tpl.php and template.php are also under that folder)
btw, I uploaded an image to show you where I was trying to display my link, after selecting display my link, I was expect Druapl to run the html markup I wrote on views-more.tpl.php but it doesn't
http://i.stack.imgur.com/8oMSg.png